# SQL - finding identical data in the dataset by joining on the table itself

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I was trying to write a sql query to find out the following -

```
User_info   column1         column2
userId1     pete            katie    
            katie           pete     
                            john    


userId2     pete            katie    
                            miles    
                            jessica  
                            pete    

userId3     jessica         pete
            matt            katie
                            john
```

So suppose my data is structured in the following fashion in SQL, where column1 and column2 are basically of type record.

If there is a name in column1 which does not belong to column2 then I want to basically report that.

So my result should look something like

```
User_info   Count
userId1     0
userId2     0
userId3     2
```

userId1 has pete and katie present in column2 and hence the count will be 0

userId2 has pete in column2 and hence the count will be 0

userId3 does not have jessica or matt in column2 and hence the count will be 2

Any ides on how I can proceed with this problem, I am unfortunately drawing a blank here. Thank you

Comment: Apologies for the late response, I marked the correct answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT User_info, 
  (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM UNNEST(column1) value 
    WHERE NOT value IN (SELECT value FROM UNNEST(column2) value)
  ) Missing_count
FROM `project.dataset.table`
```

If to apply to sample data from your question - result is

```
Row User_info   Missing_count    
1   userId1     0    
2   userId2     0    
3   userId3     2
```

Answer (score 0):

I would unnest each record seperately, than do a set difference, then aggregate:

```
with rec1 as (
  select userid, x
  from tbl 
  cross join unnest(tbl.column1) as x
), 
rec2 as (
  select userid, x
  from tbl 
  cross join unnest(tbl.column2) as x
), 
diff as (
  select * from rec1
  except 
  select * from rec2
)
select userid, count(1)
from diff
group by userid
order by userid
```

Comment: I think you have column2 and column1 backward in the logic.